# Wrong UIScrollView subviews placement

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm programmatically creating the UI of my application and i have been stuck with this problem for almost two days now.

I have my MasterViewController that creates an instance of my scrollview:

```
CGRect bottomViewFrame = CGRectMake(0,self.view.bounds.size.height-self.view.bounds.size.height/4.6,self.view.frame.size.width,100);
BottomView *bottomView = [[BottomView alloc] initWithFrame:bottomViewFrame];
```

and in my ScrollView's initWithFrame: method i have:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
    self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.pagingEnabled = YES;

    UIView* test = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    test.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self addSubview:test];

    return self;
}
```

There are a few things that does not behave correctly...
First of all, as you can see i set the ScrollView's contentSize height to it's own height but i'm still able to scroll after executing on simulator.

Second i have set the UIView "Test" with origin at (0;0) but it's displaying at some coords that seems to me like (0;self.frame.height/2).

This is the final result on the simulator

[image]

Has anyone an idea? Thanks in advance, so much.

Comment: I tried to refractor the entire code and delete random stuff to understand what was causing the error. I ended up giving the main window rootViewController the MasterViewController instead of the previous instance of UINavigationController. Seems like the scrollview is now following the expected behavior but...what? How can UINavigationController affect the UIScrollView? How can i use both, together?

Answer (score 2):

Solved! After two days of struggling i finally got the answer.
The UINavigationController was letting the MainViewController to automatically setup the UIScrollView's subviews inset, you i just had to insert into the init method of my MasterViewController

`self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;`

to solve the issue and let my views place as i want.

Comment: that's exactly!